# Replacing the end of a few hundred files

Tags: text-processing

I need to change the way a few hundred Perl modules end. Currently they end as

```
1;
```

However I need to modify this so that they all have this on their last few lines.

```
BEGIN {
    # VERSION
}
1;
# ABSTRACT: table definition
```

Of course I'm sure I could do this with Perl probably using PPI, but it also seems that I might just be able to `sed` or `awk` the end of these files. Can anyone provide any suggestions as to how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite conveniently done with GNU sed, thanks to the combination of `$` to act on the last line and `-i` to modify files in place. This assumes that the `1;` is on the very last line, otherwise it would be a lot more complicated.

```
sed -i -e '$s/^1;$/BEGIN {\
    # VERSION\
}\
1;\
# ABSTRACT: table definition/' *.pm
```

With Perl, since the files are small, just load them fully in memory. This way it's easy to be more flexible, e.g. allow spaces and comments and `__DATA__` after `1;` (allowing POD is left as an exercise to the reader).

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\s*1\s*;(?=(?:\s*(?:#.*)?\n)*(?:\s*__(?:DATA|END)__\b)?\Z)/\nBEGIN…definition/' *.pm
```